# Ошибка в кодировке русских символов

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Создал пустое asp.net приложение и добавил к ней mssql табличку. Т.е. вшитый в вижуал студию функционал. Добавляется к ней файлик, и через интерфейс студии работаю. Выполняю запрос:

```
insert into client (name, surname, patronimyc) values ('Синицын', 'Константин', 'Иванович');
```

Что из студии руками, что из кода, в таблицу пишутся знаки вопроса. С английскими символами такой проблемы нет. Тип полей nvarchar(50) у отчества попробовал varchar(50), то же самое. Когда просто без запроса руками пишу русские символы, всё нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от этой проблемы? Желательно что бы и из студии выполнялся запрос нормально и из кода.

Comment: Покажите строку подключения

Comment: При вставке в `nvarchar` столбцы литералов, содержащих кириллические (и любые другие нелатинские) символы, добавляйте перед ними `N` (что означает _national_), например: `values (N'Синицын', N'Константин', N'Иванович')`, тогда кириллические символы будут вставляться как кириллические, независимо от того какая настройка _collation_ у базы данных. Ещё лучше использовать _параметризованный запрос_, что дополнительно защитит от _sql-инъекции_.

Comment: @i-one, а почему тогда при инсерте в обычный варчар происходит то же самое?

Comment: Какой используется Collation?

Comment: `nvarchar` хранит юникод (utf16, 2 байта на символ), а `varchar` - не-юникод (1 байт на символ) в кодировке, определяемой свойством collation столбца (по-умолчанию совпадает с collation базы данных). Для `varchar`, соответственно, если в collation задана латиница, а литерал вставляется кириллический, то он не может быть нормально кодирован и вместо кириллических символов вставятся `???`.